# How to do partial search in Linux with locate?

Tags: linux, search

I prefer to seach with `locate` command but I don't know how to perform a partial search with it.

Suppose I want to search file containing the word `libevent`. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try `man locate` in a terminal ?

Comment: Do you want a *file* containing 'libevent' or a *filename* containing 'libevent'? The two are quite different!

Comment: I wanted both , in the name and contents as well. i was comfortable with locate but i think i need to use grep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate searches for file names. Not file contents.

The ugly way is to use grep It'll start searching from `/` directory.

```
grep -irn 'libevent' /
```

The better way is to narrow down the suspected directories where this files could exists. Suppose those directories' full paths are `/path/to/dir1`, `/path/to/dir2` etc. Then invoke the following command.

```
for dir in /path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2
do 
     grep -irn 'libevent' $dir
done
```

Comment: Except that there are some directories that you want to avoid, like `/proc/` and perhaps `/tmp/`

Answer (score 0):

The `locate` command is not searching inside the content of files like `grep` (and other commands) do. It is simply searching inside file paths.

`locate` work by using a cache index of file paths, and this index is often updated by the `updatedb` utility.

### addenda

A useful way to search some pattern inside (the content of) some files is to use the ability of `zsh` or some recent versions of `bash` to expand the `**` file pattern, like e.g.

```
grep foo ~/gee/**/*.[ch]
```

with *zsh* this search inside all files named `*.c` or `*.h` under `$HOME/gee/` containing `foo`. I find this feature tremendously useful, and justifying alone the adoption of [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) as my interactive shell. With other shells you might type the much longer

```
find $HOME/gee -name '*.ch' | xargs grep foo
```

Comment: how can i search for partail filenames in locate

Comment: I don't understand that question. `locate foo` gives you a set of file names containing `foo` like `/home/jo/dir/abfoox.c` or `/other/dir/withfooinside/bar.h`